# Error message in my controller creation, Define the key for this entity type

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio, key

I get the following error message when I try to add a controller for my database:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HyoN.png

```
Unable to retrieve metadata for 'MvcPractise.Models.Payments'. One or more validation errors were detected during model generation.

System.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'PaymentsContext' has no key defined. Define the key for this Entity type.

Systyem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet:EntityType:EntitySet 'Payment' is based on the type 'Payment Context' that has no keys defined.
```

I am exceedingly new to Visual Studio, C# and ASP MVC.net, been following a tutorial, but slightly varying the attributes to better suit the needs for what my assignment requires.

My code looks as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using MvcPractise.Models;

namespace MvcPractise.Models {

public class Payments {

    [Key]
    public String Email { get; set; }
    public String PaypalEmail { get; set; }
    public String CardHoldersName { get; set; }
    public String CardNumber { get; set; }
    public String ExpirationDate { get; set; }
    public String CardType { get; set; }


}

public class PaymentsContext : DbContext
{

    public DbSet<PaymentsContext> Payment { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Payments> Payments { get; set; }

}
}
```

If anyone can help, I've been searching through this site and trying many possible solutions, I'v recreated the database and rewritten the code, restarted VS, added the [Key] type as you can see in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename `class Payments` to `class Payment`.

Then your PaymentsContext should be:

```
public class PaymentsContext: DbContext
{
   public DbSet<Payment> Payments { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe the problem is in  your PaymentsContext class. You define a DbSet Payment property which I don't think you meant to do. The PaymentsContext class is just a derived class of DbContext and shouldn't be a property of itself. The following should fix your problem:

```
    public class PaymentsContext : DbContext
    {
            public DbSet<Payments> Payments { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked perfectly, I spent hours trying to fix this. I love you.